# Correct way of calculating percentile

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

I have a table with column names as: `col1, col2, Values`. I need to find the 99th percentile of `Values` for each pair of unique `col1, col2` identifiers. i.e. value for which 99% of the `Values` are less.

I tried the following:

```
    SELECT [col1], [col2],
   PERCENTILE_CONT(0.99) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Values] ASC) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY [col1], [col2]) "Percentile_Cont"   
FROM MyTable
```

However, it produces repeated `[col1], [col2]` pair.

What is the suggested correct implementation to get unique pairs of `[col1], [col2]` with their corresponding percentiles?

Edit:
Sample data:

```
col1 col2 values
A   a2  1
A   a2  2
A   a2  1
A   a2  12
B   a1  11
B   a1  11
B   a1  12
B   a1  15
```

expected answer:

```
A   a2  11.7
B   a1  14.91
```

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Comment: Try using `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT [col1], [col2], 
  PERCENTILE_CONT(0.99) 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [Values] ASC) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY [col1], [col2]) "Percentile_Cont"   
FROM MyTable
```